# How to custom-set-faces with one of the named faces?

Tags: font-lock, custom

I can do this:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(j-verb-face ((t (:foreground "Red")))))
```

But what I want is to set the color to one that is theme-dependent.

I tried the following, which causes a "wrong argument type" error:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(j-verb-face ((t (font-lock-function-name-face)))))
```

How can I set the color of `j-verb-face` to be `font-lock-function-name-face`?

Comment: Try `((t (:inherit font-lock-function-name-face)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simpler solution!

```lisp
(setq j-verb-face font-lock-function-name-face)
```

Comment: Not all faces have corresponding variables with the same name.  Your solution assumes that the code used to apply the face references the variable (rather than the face name) [written slightly differently, such as as a single quote preceding the face name], and that both `j-verb-face` and `font-lock-function-name-face` have been assigned variables with the same name as the face (which happens to be the case here, but certainly not always).

Comment: Yeah, I [read recently](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_define_face.html) that faces are not variables, which is weird to me. This solution seemed to work when I tried it, but I have no idea what edge cases may exist.

Comment: It depends on the face and how the font-lock rule are written. font-lock *evalute* the face field of font-lock rules. If they contain the quoted name of the, as in `(0 'my-face)`, then this method won't work. However, if it contains the unquoted name, as in `(0 my-face)` then font-lock reads the variable named `my-face` which typically contains the name of the face, equally typically a face with the same name as the variable. Using the variable way is deprecated -- if it works in this case I'm glad, but it wont work for all cases.